# auto bcc is not working when contain attachment in Postfix

Tags: server, postfix

I'm using postfix smtp and adding always_bcc.

```
always_bcc = admin@somesite.com
```

It's working fine without attachment. When I add attachment, auto bcc is not working and admin didn't get email.

How to fix that problem ?

Comment: This question is a bit off topic! You should try to ask it at http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This question is not off-topic. It is a legitimate problem that can occur on Ubuntu servers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that this question wasn't valid here! Just that is might be more valid (or better solved by) on unix.stachexchange or serverfault.

Comment: This is already on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/176449/auto-bcc-is-not-working-when-contain-attachment-in-postfix

Comment: does this happen also when the attachment is very very small (a couple of bytes) ?

Comment: Are you getting anything in the log files relating to this? Is it that it is attempting delivery but some external factor is preventing it being delivered, such as the admin@somesite.com rejecting emails with attachments? Postfix is not selective about applying always_bcc it applies it to every message irrespective.

Answer (score 2):

This is not answer i just trying to say a way to debug your postifx server configuration

> post postconf -n

and see the postfix Troubleshooting process [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html)

also see Postfix sends all log messages to /var/log/mail.log. However error and warning messages can sometimes get lost in the normal log output so they are also logged to /var/log/mail.err and /var/log/mail.warn respectively.